# Python : extract all items that match a pattern

Tags: python, string, split

is there a strait forward way in python to extract all items that match a pattern, specifically all items between 2 characters (for example $$)

I have tried using

```
split("$""$")
```

on a string that looks like this

```
string = "$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$"
```

with the aim of getting something that looks like this

```
string = [ $This$, $is$, $some$, $data$ ]
```

however this doesn't work, is there a strait forward way to extract everything that matches a pattern like this in python?

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, you need to use `re.findall` with lazy match. Without the lazy match operator, the first `$` and the last `$` will be matched and you get the entire string.

**Without lazy match**

```
In [37]: pattern = "$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$"

In [38]: regex = r'\$.*\$'

In [39]: print re.findall(regex, string)
['$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$']
```

**With lazy match**

```
In [40]: pattern = "$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$"

In [41]: pattern = "$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$"

In [42]: regex = r'\$.*?\$'

In [43]: print re.findall(regex, string)
['$This$', '$is$', '$some$', '$data$']
```

However in the question, you mention all items between two characters. You may want to use the following:

```
In [44]: pattern = "$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$"

In [45]: regex = r'\$(.*?)\$'

In [46]: print re.findall(regex, string)
['This', 'is', 'some', 'data']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall` with **lazy** match:

```
In [76]: re.findall(r'\$.*?\$', s)  #note the "?" here
Out[76]: ['$This$', '$is$', '$some$', '$data$']
```

see [non-greedy qualifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy)

Answer (score 1):

How about the following code?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$"
>>> re.findall(r'\$[^$]*\$', s)
['$This$', '$is$', '$some$', '$data$']
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand `str.split`. It takes the delimiter as the argument- it does not get strings that fulfil a certain criteria such as being crufted with certain characters. When you said that you wanted to get all strings that were crufted with certain characters, I had 'regular expressions' screaming in my ear.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "$This$ $is$ $some$ $data$"
>>> re.findall(r'\$[^$]*\$', string)
['$This$', '$is$', '$some$', '$data$']
```